# How to create proper relationships in database design

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a database to rate professors as part of an asp.net mvc project. I am creating it using entity framework code first. The following will be the tables:

```
User
Professor
Ratings
Comment
```

`User` and `Professor` will have a many-to-many relationship.

There will be four questionnaires which can be rated from 1 to 5 and will be saved in the `Ratings` table. So, there will be four rows in the `Ratings` table per user per professor. One comment per user per professor in the `Comment` table.

To query a given user's ratings and comments, I think to get a given user's ratings, I have to go by per userid, professorid, Ratingsid  and then commentid related to userid and professorid. Need help in how to create these tables with proper relationship.

Thanks

Comment: As you mention in question same relation made, professor is master table for all, userid also included in both rating and comment table ,but don't stuff at backend level your actual work depend on your frontend

Comment: Nazir, Don't you think that the Ratings and Comment tables should have both the ProfessorId and The UserId?

Comment: Please clarify "questionnaires". Do you mean individual questions? Do you allow one comment per question or one comment per set of questions (you say it is 4 questions or questioneers)? Do you need to store data about questions / questioneers?

Comment: please make dummy data chart and show for table , where we guess what you actually want...

Comment: Hi Nazir, I have added a link to the ER diagram which is http://i66.tinypic.com/qqphep.png